# Is there a reason why Google Apps Script won't return a full range of dates from a sheet?

Tags: date, google-apps-script, google-sheets

What I'm trying to do is very simple, so I'm hoping someone here can help me figure out why it's not working as expected.

In my original Google Sheet, I have 3 columns of data; column 1 has dates from Jan 01 2023 to Dec 31 2023, column 2 is the same date, but formatted as a single number, ie 1, 2, 3, etc, column 3 is just text.

When I try to Logger.log the data, it fails part way through and without giving any kind of error message. It doesn't even finish logging out the array for the row it's currently writing. It works perfectly if there are no dates involved, but as soon as I have multiple dates, I get the same result...

I've included some of the code I've been trying, but I've also tried copying the data to a new sheet (within the original Spreadsheet), pasting values only, which obviously gives me dates as numbers, but I still get the same result. I've also tried retrieving the data in batches of 50 and have tried the same series of tests with a brand new Spreadsheet in a different directory - I still get the same result (where it cuts off in the log differs from time to time, but there's nothing obvious as to why). For all sheets I've tried, if I remove all the dates and just use numbers (1 to 365), the full data is retrieved as expected.

Is there something in-built preventing dates being logged out in this way?

FWIW here's the code *(I've added it as a snippet just to save space)*:

```js
// Can't get it to find the last row of the data range
const sheetId = "1_N4W_XXXXXX"
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetId);
const detailSheet = ss.getSheetByName("MultiLine Details");
const data = detailSheet.getRange(2, 1, 28, 3).getValues(); // Original - from row 2, col 1, get 28 rows, 3 cols - this works fine, even with dates

// Extend the range to include up to and including the last row 
const data2 = detailSheet.getRange(2, 1, detailSheet.getLastRow()-1, 3).getValues(); // Won't return past row 99 
// Even if I remove -1 from getLastRow or use 366 (the actual number of rows), it returns the exact same range

const dataLastRow = detailSheet.getLastRow(); // returns 366.0, which is correct

function test(){ 

  Logger.log(dataLastRow); // returns 366.0, so it can see the last row
  Logger.log(data2); // returns data to row 99 only
  Logger.log(detailSheet.getLastRow()); // returns 366.0

}

// Tried the above with a brand new sheet in a different directory in my Drive - same result

// Test batching using brand new Sheet - same result
function newTest2() {
const sheetId2 = "1Loa8_XXXXXX"
const ss2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetId2);
const detailSheet2 = ss2.getSheetByName("NewSheet1");

const numRows2 = detailSheet2.getLastRow();
const numCols2 = detailSheet2.getLastColumn();
const batchSize2 = 50; // number of rows to retrieve at a time

let data2 = [];

for (let i = 2; i <= numRows2; i += batchSize2) {
  const numRowsToGet2 = Math.min(batchSize2, numRows2 - i + 1);
  const range2 = detailSheet2.getRange(i, 1, numRowsToGet2, numCols2);
  const batchData2 = range2.getValues();
  data2 = data2.concat(batchData2);
}

  Logger.log(data2);
};

// Test batching using original Sheet - same result
function newTest() {
const sheetId = "1_N4W_XXXXXX"
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetId);
const detailSheet = ss.getSheetByName("MultiLine Details");

const numRows = detailSheet.getLastRow();
const numCols = detailSheet.getLastColumn();
const batchSize = 50; // number of rows to retrieve at a time

let data = [];

for (let i = 2; i <= numRows; i += batchSize) {
  const numRowsToGet = Math.min(batchSize, numRows - i + 1);
  const range = detailSheet.getRange(i, 1, numRowsToGet, numCols);
  const batchData = range.getValues();
  data = data.concat(batchData);
}

  Logger.log(data);
};
```

Comment: "// Can't get it to find the last row of the data range"... `var lastRow = detailSheet.getLastRow()`, 
 `Logger.log("the last row = "+lastRow)`. If that doesn't work, then there is a problem with either the name of the sheet, or the ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You believe that your script is not returning all of the rows in a range, but only 99 of the rows.

When using `Logger.log(data2);`, the response is displayed on screen but because the variable could be extremely long, only a subset is returned. The output begins "Logging output too large. Truncating output."

However, the data variable does contain ALL of the rows of values. There are several ways to confirm this. In the answer below,

- `Logger.log("number of rows of data:"+data.length)` returns the actual number of rows in the data
- `colDRange.setValues(data)` pastes the data (all 365 rows) to the spreadsheet.

---

```
function test01(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sheetName = "MultiLine Details"
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName)
  //var testRange = sheet.getRange(2, 1, 28, 3)
  //Logger.log("the range = "+testRange.getA1Notation())
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow()
  //Logger.log("the last row = "+lastRow)
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow()-1, 3)
  Logger.log("the data range = "+dataRange.getA1Notation())
  var data = dataRange.getValues()
  Logger.log("number of rows of data:"+data.length)
  
  // this will return a subset because 
  // "Logging output too large. Truncating output."
  Logger.log(data)

  // proof that data has 365 rows of values
  var colDRange = sheet.getRange(2, 4, sheet.getLastRow()-1,3)
  Logger.log("the Column d range = "+colDRange.getA1Notation())
  colDRange.setValues(data)

}
```

Comment: Thank you Tedinoz for taking the time to explain what was happening - I'm sure others will find it helpful too. Being relatively new to js & App Script, I assumed I was doing something wrong

Comment: You're quite right, my apologies :)